# Why is Policy Gradient method for Reinforcement Learning good for LARGE action spaces

Tags: gradient, policy

As stated in the title, I have read multiple sources that Policy Gradient methods are RL are suitable for large actions spaces, but I dont understand why is this so.

I am trying to see if RL can tackle a problem of mine that has a huge combinatorial no. of possible actions. Hypothetically it is about sending n no. of items from location i to j. Any combination of (i,j,n) is a possible action, and (i,j,n) all have magnitude in the 1000s, this makes more than a billion possible actions.

Since the output layer nodes of the neural net in Policy Gradient methods represents the no. of actions. With >1000,000,000 possible actions, how can Policy Gradient be a good method to solve such problems?

Answer (score 0):

For large or continuous action spaces, you need to use **function approximation** methods to approximate the optimal policy. This is known as policy approximation. There are a number of possible approaches that include least-squares optimization or gradient-based optimization. Nearly all of these techniques utilize random sampling to produce and compare possible actions that maximize return over the infinite-time horizon.

From Sutton and Barto's RL book [1](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf):

> Policy-based methods offer practical ways of dealing with large action spaces, even continuous spaces with an inﬁnite number of actions. Instead of computing learned probabilities for each of the many actions, we instead learn statistics of the probability distribution. For example, the action set might be the real numbers, with actions chosen from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

Check out:

- Section 13.7 in [Sutton and Barto's](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) book for more theoretical explanation
- [This](https://github.com/cyoon1729/RLcycle) GitHub repo for code examples that have viable approaches for this problem

Comment: Thank you. So for my above example with possibly >1billion actions, what should the output layer of my neural network be in the Policy Gradient method? I can't possibly have one node for one action.

Comment: It depends on the dimensionality of the action space. Let's say your environment is that of a 2D car that must park itself at some point on a graph. The agent is tasked with controlling the car by inputting 2 variables: force and turning torque. So your agent must predict a 2-dimensional vector: [F, M], where both are continuous variables. In this case, the final layer in the NN would be 2-dimensional (having 2 units).

Comment: Note that unlike in discrete action spaces, where the neural net predicts the probability distribution over multiple actions - in the case of policy *approximation* in the continuous action space, the output is a single action, whether it is 1-dimensional or N-dimensional.